# map branch to remote?

Tags: git, branch

I have a GIT question. I am in branch xx , which I confirmed with `git status`. But `git branch` shows a bunch of branches, without `*` beside branch xx. And xx branch is not green colour.  I tried `git branch -u origin/xx`, but still don't see the `*` . I tried a `git pull` and get this error:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the  ref 'refs/heads/xx'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

Any suggestions who to make my xx branch map to origin xx branch, and do a pull?
Thanks, Peter

Comment: Without actual cut-and-paste output it's not clear why `git status` claims you're on a branch and `git branch` disagrees. The `git pull` complaint (which I've reformatted) tells us more: that branch `xx` has an upstream set, but it's set to a branch that does not exist now on the remote (most likely, it used to but they deleted it since then).

Answer (score 0):

Git remote -v would give the origin branch.

git remote set-url origin ( http link) to map to your origin.

Check out the article for more details - https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/